# OSGI un used Import packages make as optional

Tags: java, osgi, aem, apache-felix, felix-dependency-manager

Am trying to create an aem workflow java process step, adding the below dependency in the pom.xml file dependencies list once i add the bundle build is fine but it is in Installed state only because of the below two errors.

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.day.cq.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>cq-workflow-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

i have tried adding the dependency but still no use, the error remains same

```
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
<artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
<version>2.8.3</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
```

And also i have tried to keep the imports as optional still no use

```
<Import-Package>net.sf.ehcache,net.spy.memcached,*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>
```

Error Message:
[image: Error message in AEM Felix console]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the build time dependencies to ehcache and memcached as `<optional>true</optional>` in the maven pom. bnd will then create the imports as optional and it should work. No need to have a Import-Package Element.

Comment: I have added in this way
 `<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.3</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.spy</groupId>
    <artifactId>spymemcached</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>`
Bundle in installed status and below error message shows in red.
net.sf.ehcache,version=[2.8,3) -- Cannot be resolved but is not required
net.spy.memcached -- Cannot be resolved but is not required

Comment: Check the Manifest if the import is optional. If it is optional then the bundle should resolve.